# An adjective for a 'good definition'?

Tags: word-request

I am looking for an *idiomatic* adjective for a definition that is good. I know that a definition must be to-the-point, precise, clear, exact, accurate, etc. But what adjective do we usually use when talking about a good definition? I am interested in both an an *idiomatic* words used frequently everywhere and a *jargons* used frequently in academic texts.

Comment: Do you mean "definition" as in how we define the meaning of words?  It has several possible meanings, e.g. a "high-definition computer monitor"

Comment: Maybe “comprehensive”

Comment: A "term" is a single word or phrase "used frequently in academic texts."  A "jargon" is a collection of such "terms" used in an academic field.  Different fields can have different jargons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "well-defined" concept has a good definition.  [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/well-defined) says:

> Something that is well-defined is clear and precise and therefore easy to recognize or understand.

A "well-defined" measurable quantity was defined clearly enough that if someone else had made the measurement instead, they would have interpreted what they were looking at the same way.  This implies that a "well-defined" measurable quantity can be measured repeatably.